# Evaluating multiple leap years

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, leap-year

I need to modify this program I made that checks years if they are leap years. the modifications have to evaluate multiple years until the user wants to end by sentinel value. I also have to have each year to verify whether it is less than 1582 and say invalid or redirect to the error message again. been unsure of how i can accomplish this, thanks for any help that can be given

```
int year;
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);      
System.out.print("Please input year(s) (-1 to end): ");
year = myScanner.nextInt(); 
while (year != -1)
{
    while (year < 1582)
    {
        System.out.print("Error (enter value greater than or equal to 1582 (-1 to exit to main): ");
        year = myScanner.nextInt();
        if (year >= 1582 || year == -1)
            break;
    }
    if (year >= 1582)
        if ((year % 4 != 0) || (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0))
            System.out.print("Sorry, this value is not a leap year.");
        else
            System.out.print("This value is a leap year.");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close; an easier way to do this would be something like this.

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);      
System.out.print("Please input year(s) (-1 to end): ");
year = myScanner.nextInt(); 
for (; year != -1; year = myScanner.nextInt(); 
{
    if (year < 1582)
    {
        System.out.print("Error (enter value greater than or equal to 1582, or -1 to exit to main): ");
        continue;
    }
    if ((year % 4 != 0) || (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0))
        System.out.print("Sorry, this value is not a leap year.");
    else
        System.out.print("This value is a leap year.");
    System.out.print("Please input year(s) (-1 to end): ");
}
```

I think it's always tricky to get response loops correct and also looking nice. In this case, you were using `break` where I think you meant to use `continue`. You don't need a special loop for the error, though; you can do it by printing the error prompt and kicking it back to the main read loop.